# Perform Group By Operation with multiple attributes on Azure Aggregates API

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

Our problem is, How to perform group by operation with multiple attributes?
As a example, lets assume we have a  bellow event schema:

```
{
    {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "String"
    },
    {
        "name": "last_updated_at",
        "type": "Double"
    },
    {
        "name": "location_cell",
        "type": "String"
    }
}
```

And we want to perform group by operation with all of above attributes (fields) and get a count as a result.

Can we use only aggregate API without any changes to schema to fulfill this requirement? If it is how to set multiple values for  **uniqueValues**?
Or should we need to add a new attribute (field) to schema with string concatenation of all of above fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, the maximum depth supported in 5, i.e. you can group by a maximum of 5 properties.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/ga-query-api